# Network configuration for transparent proxy

Tags: networking, proxy, squid

I'm trying deployment Squid in my house; as much as cache server, as much transparent proxy.

I having questions about your network configuration. I am going to describe my environment.

- I have as a router a Mikrotik, as which management my network 192.168.80.0/24 and work as a gateway.
- My idea is deploy squid in a personal server as which only have a one network card and is connected a my mikrotik router. This server have set a ip 192.168.80.10 with his gateway 192.168.80.1
- All endpoints have as a gateway ip 192.168.80.1

My question is born at moment that configure gateway in the endpoints.

- Should configure in my DHCP server that all endpoints take ip proxy (192.168.80.10) and inside squid configure iptables rules for direct all traffic to the gateway?
- Or the configuration correct way is that endpoints have your gateway 192.168.80.1 and from mikrotik redirect all http/https traffic at squid server and then return send to router?

Waiting for your help, thanks! Attach a little diagram.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/8waqU.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is perfectly doable, you just need to configure policy-based-routing on mikrotik and redirect traffic to a separate squid box. See full tutorial at https://docs.diladele.com/tutorials/mikrotik_transparent_squid/index.html